# Multiple forms submitting with single view - Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I have two ModelForms submitting from a single view. One model is a ForeignKey of another. At this point, the form will add to the DB, but not as expected. Instead of adding a Course and a Section (with course field populated with the newly-created Course), I'm getting a Course and Section that are linked, but with the Section name that was entered as both the Course name and the Section name.

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    Active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.Name)

class Section(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='.',unique=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assessments = models.ManyToManyField(Assessment)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s / %s' % (self.Name, self.course)
```

forms.py

```
class CourseAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ['Name', 'Active']
class SectionAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Section
        fields = ['Name']
```

templates/index.html

```
<!-- COURSE ADD MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="CourseAddModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header" style="padding:5px 10px;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4>Add Course</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px 10px;">
      <form data-parsley-validate method="post" id="coursesecaddform" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                data-parsley-trigger="focusout">

        {% csrf_token %}
        Add course
        {{ courseaddform.as_p }}
        Add section
        {{ sectionaddform.as_p }}

        <p id="login-error"></p>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info submit" name="AddCourse" value="Add Course" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def IndexView(request,Course_id,Section_id):
    if request.method == "GET":

        this_course = Course.objects.get(pk=Course_id)
        active_courses = Course.objects.all().filter(Active=True).exclude(pk=Course_id)
        section_list = Section.objects.all().filter(course=this_course)
        if len(section_list) >1:
            multi_section = True
        else:
            multi_section = False
        active_section = Section.objects.get(pk=Section_id)
        roster = Student.objects.all().filter(sections__in=[active_section])
        announcement_list = Announcement.objects.all().filter(sections__in=[active_section])
        courseaddform = CourseAddForm()
        sectionaddform = SectionAddForm()

        context = {'active_courses':active_courses, 'this_course': this_course,
                   'active_section':active_section, 'section_list':section_list,
                   'roster':roster, 'multi_section':multi_section,
                   'announcement_list':announcement_list, 'courseaddform':courseaddform,
                   'sectionaddform':sectionaddform}
        return render(request,'gbook/index.html', context)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        this_course = Course.objects.get(pk=Course_id)
        active_courses = Course.objects.all().filter(Active=True).exclude(pk=Course_id)
        section_list = Section.objects.all().filter(course=this_course)
        if len(section_list) >1:
            multi_section = True
        else:
            multi_section = False
        active_section = Section.objects.get(pk=Section_id)

        f = CourseAddForm(request.POST, instance=Course())
        g = SectionAddForm(request.POST, instance=Section())
        if f.is_valid() and g.is_valid():
            new_course = f.save()
            new_section = g.save(commit=False)
            new_section.course = new_course
            print new_section.course
            new_section.save()

        return redirect("/gbook/"+str(Course_id)+"/"+str(active_section))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Instead of using the `instance` argument, use `prefix`:

```
def IndexView(request,Course_id,Section_id):
    if request.method == "GET":

        this_course = Course.objects.get(pk=Course_id)
        active_courses = Course.objects.all().filter(Active=True).exclude(pk=Course_id)
        section_list = Section.objects.all().filter(course=this_course)
        if len(section_list) >1:
            multi_section = True
        else:
            multi_section = False
        active_section = Section.objects.get(pk=Section_id)
        roster = Student.objects.all().filter(sections__in=[active_section])
        announcement_list = Announcement.objects.all().filter(sections__in=[active_section])
        courseaddform = CourseAddForm(prefix='crs')
        sectionaddform = SectionAddForm(prefix='sctn')

        context = {'active_courses':active_courses, 'this_course': this_course,
                   'active_section':active_section, 'section_list':section_list,
                   'roster':roster, 'multi_section':multi_section,
                   'announcement_list':announcement_list, 'courseaddform':courseaddform,
                   'sectionaddform':sectionaddform}
        return render(request,'gbook/index.html', context)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        this_course = Course.objects.get(pk=Course_id)
        active_courses = Course.objects.all().filter(Active=True).exclude(pk=Course_id)
        section_list = Section.objects.all().filter(course=this_course)
        if len(section_list) >1:
            multi_section = True
        else:
            multi_section = False
        active_section = Section.objects.get(pk=Section_id)

        f = CourseAddForm(request.POST, prefix='crs')
        g = SectionAddForm(request.POST, prefix='sctn')
        if f.is_valid() and g.is_valid():
            new_course = f.save()
            new_section = g.save(commit=False)
            new_section.course = new_course
            print new_section.course
            new_section.save()

        return redirect("/gbook/"+str(Course_id)+"/"+str(active_section))
```

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, `instance` allows you to prepopulate a form with data and/or edit an existing model instance. `prefix` sticks a unique prefix onto the name and ID attributes of the generated form fields, which is probably the ideal way to solve your issue. It's not really an "either `instance` or `prefix`" choice, because they do different things and can even be used at the same time. Again, to be clear, I think using `prefix` is the right call here.

Comment: Thank you for the context! It's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Both models have a `Name` field, so both forms contain an input with identical `name` attribute. When Django encounters two POST parameters with the same name, it binds the last one's value to all fields by that name. Long story short - change field names in your models so they are different.

Comment: I found an alternate solution (see my answer above), but would changing those field names allow my old code to work as written?

Comment: Yes, although I think I like your solution more, I can easily imagine a situation where changing model field names would be at least troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Course` and `Section` both have an attribute called `Name`, I am betting that your form has two fields with the attributes `id = "id_Name"` and `name = "Name"`.